# System.Net.GlobalLog - How do I view the output of this?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, logging

Many classes in the .NET framework (especially in the socket/network classes, which is what I'm looking at) use System.Net.GlobalLog (an internal class) to log trace messages somewhere. You can view example uses of things like GlobalLog.Assert and GlobalLog.Print in the SslState class:

[SslStream source code](http://www.wikiencyclopedia.net/FX-1434/1.0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/SecureProtocols/_SslStream.cs/2/_SslStream.cs)

This is different from the System.Net.Logging (also internal) class, uses of which can also be found throughout the socket/network classes.

For System.Net.Logging, I know I can use a <system.diagnostics> configuration block in App.Config and that will result in System.Net.Logging messages getting logged if configured properly. However, this does not appear to influence System.Net.GlobalLog.

After searching around for about an hour, I cannot seem to find any information about locating the output of System.Net.GlobalLog. Does anyone know how to locate/view/control the output of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, GlobalLog is an internal class to the System.Net assembly.  Without being able to modify the System.Net assembly you won't get access to that class.

That said, you might want to review the following: http://www.123aspx.com/rotor/RotorSrc.aspx?rot=42941

It looks like you have to have compiler flags `TRAVE` and `DEBUG` set in order to get it to work.. but I'm not seeing where it actually does anything with the logged information.  The comments suggest that it is supposed to look for an environment variable setting and dump the log to a text file somewhere on the system; however the code at that page seems either incomplete or it simply wasn't finished.

My guess is that you need to find some other way of getting access to the logging info you want.

Comment: What it boiled down to was that, without having a debug/trave-compiled version of the System.dll library, I wasn't going to get that information. Also, the source code of these classes can't be stepped through in Visual Studio, so it's impossible to realistically debug what's going on. While your answer didn't solve my problem, it WAS the right answer.

The ultimate solution to my problem ended up being "ditch SslStream and go with BouncyCastle's TLS implementation." I was already using that library for certificate generation, so this didn't add extra dependencies to my project.

Comment: Additionally, System.Net.Logging is also an internal class, and yet there is a documented way to view/direct the output of that class. Just not GlobalLog. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to put this as a comment on the existing answer but I wanted to figure out what was happening in the TcpClient and Socket classes but also found they couldn't be stepped into. The closest I got was by monitoring the Windows API calls that were being made. I used a freeware tool called API Monitor found here: http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor.